# RegEx to match sentence containing fixed number of commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to match sentence with a certain number of commas. Assuming sentence starts with '. '.

Although I managed to get what I want, my RegEx somehow matches the whole paragraph.

So in other words, I'd like to delimit beginning of this to just one sentence.

My code is as follows:

```
/(?:\.+.+\,+.+\,+.+\,+.+\,+.+)/ig
```

I'm doing it in js, btw.

And the dummy paragraph I am working with:

This is RegEx. Whether you think so, too. I'm telling you, this, is what, I, think about this.

Comment: to  vinayakj — I've tried this, not working as it matches two sentences instead of one.

Comment: Now a solution, yet I suggest removing all repeated code and making your expression more readable by instead doing /(?:\.+.+(\,+.+){4})/ig

Comment: The problem here is in combining ?: with the regular matching regime, as I see it.

Comment: Hey, let me know if you find a regex that can tell what a sentence is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/\.(?:(?:[^,\.]+,){4}[^,\.]+)/.exec('This is RegEx. Whether you think so, too. I\'m telling you, this, is what, I, think about this.')[0]
```

returns

> . I'm telling you, this, is what, I, think about this

Comment: If I could give 1 000 000 000 rep to you, I would.